# How would I get the X postion of the right side of text in pillow

Tags: python-imaging-library

I need help trying to find out how to get the X position of the right side of the text, not to be confused with anchors or alignments, I haven't seen this be answered anywhere so if you could help then that would be great!

Comment: Do you have some code? And a diagram showing what you are trying to measure please?

Comment: I was able to find it on my own, all i had to do was provide the text, get the max and box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled it on my own:
What you need to do is:
Provide the text e.g: test = "hello"
then get mask and box e.g: test_width = FontNameHere.getmask(test).getbbox()[2]